# Conda install -c bioninja gseapy throws error

Tags: python

I have the following problem. I have installed the textblob packages (pip install textblog). But for some reason it's not recognized. When I click on the package and try to install it I get -

```
Package missing in current win-64 channels:
```

Following a stackoverflow post I tried to resolve this doing:

```
conda install -c bioninja gseapy
```

This however gives me another error:

```
Attempting to roll back
LinkError: post-link failed....
```

So im kind of lost now with what should be the next step. Any thoughts based on the errors above?

Answer (score 0):

I see you try to run `pip install textblog` but misspelled it

**try using** `pip install textblob`

works for me...